# Can't share intent to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, share

I can't share a string to Facebook. It works fine with email, sms etc, but nothing at all with Facebook, I open it and it's just blank.

Do you know if I need any permission (apart from the internet connection in the manifest) or library or else?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //create the send intent

            String result = builder.toString();

            Intent shareIntent =
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "This is your list");

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, result);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose how to share your list"));
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you registered your app here https://developers.facebook.comhttps://developers.facebook.com ?

Comment: Hi Burak, thanks a lot for your feedback. I will look into FB API but in the meanwhile it's annoying that clicking on my personal share button I get FB among the other choice which in the end does not work. Any idea on how I can disable it?

Comment: I am not sure I understood you correctly.You mean you are getting choices like twitter etc?If you are using emulator, it might not be working with facebook. I got similar issues when i tested my face app with emulator.

Comment: Hi Burak, I am actually trying it on my own smartphone

Comment: This is by design on some devices as a spam prevention measure.